# make softkeyboard of Android platform to overlay above the content instead of pushing it upwards

Tags: android, angularjs, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Of course there were many similar questions to my problem but none of them worked for me. So,it forced me to open a new question.

So, I am developing an Hybrid mobile app where the main screen contains two independent section with their own input labels. So,when ever the input field got focused the native Android SoftKeyboard pushing the contents of lower section towards up, which eventually decreases the screen size.

Here, I don't want the keyboard to push the content up. The keyboard should be shown but it should be over lay on the section.

I've tried these things already:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`, `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and some jquery code but in vain.

Comment: Try to use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is possible.

However you can work around this, by specifying your element's height with viewport width `vw` measures.

For example:

```
div {
    height: 40vw;
}
```

This won't work on landscape however.

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide elements when the keyboard is opened (so instead of them being pushed up, they are just not seen) by assigning the class hide-on-keyboard-open
Like so:

```
<div class="button hide-on-keyboard-open"></div>
```